# Tensorflow2.0 training: model.compile vs GradientTape

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I am starting to learn Tensorflow2.0 and one major source of my confusion is when to use the *keras-like* `model.compile` vs `tf.GradientTape` to train a model.

On the Tensorflow2.0 tutorial for MNIST classification they train two similar models. [One with `model.compile`](https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/tutorials/quickstart/beginner) and the [other with `tf.GradientTape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/tutorials/quickstart/advanced).

Apologies if this is trivial, but when do you use one over the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is really a case-specific thing and it's difficult to give a definite answer here (it might border on "too opinion-based). But in general, I would say

- The "classic" Keras interface (using `compile`, `fit`etc.) allows for quick and easy building, training & evaluation of standard models. However, it is very high-level/abstract and as such doesn't give you much low-level control. If you are implementing models with non-trivial control flow, this can be hard to accommodate.
- `GradientTape` gives you full low-level control over all aspects of training/running your model, allowing easier debugging as well as more complex architectures etc., but you will need to write more boilerplate code for many things that a `compiled` model will hide from you (e.g. training loops). Still, if you do research in deep learning you will probably be working on this level most of the time.

Comment: Hi xdurch0, thanks for your answer. I had another question I hope you could help with here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56067340/converting-short-tensorflow-1-13-script-into-tensorflow-2-0

Comment: My issue is that in the examples I’ve seen training done with model.fit but in my case I don’t have neural network so I don’t have model.