# Converting short tensorflow 1.13 script into tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to learn the dynamics of tensorflow2.0 by converting my tensorflow1.13 script (below) into a tensorflow2.0 script. However I am struggling to do this.

I think the main reason why I am struggling is because the examples of tensorflow2.0 I have seen train neural networks and so they have a `model` which they `compile` and `fit`. However in my simple example below I am not using a neural network so I can't see how to adapt this code to tensorflow2.0 (For example, how do I replace session?). Help is much appreciated and thanks in advance.

```
data = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
theta = tf.Variable(np.zeros(100))
p_s = tf.nn.softmax(theta)

loss = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.log(tf.gather(p_s, data)))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for epoch in range(10):
        for datum in sample_data(): #sample_data() is a list of integer datapoints
            _ = sess.run([train_step], feed_dict={data:datum})
    print(sess.run(p_s))
```

I have looked at [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/guide/migration_guide#low-level_variables_operator_execution) (which is most relavant) and so far I have come up with the below:

```
#data = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
theta = tf.Variable(np.zeros(100))
p_s = tf.nn.softmax(theta)

loss = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.math.log(tf.gather(p_s, **data**)))
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()

for epoch in range(10):
    for datum in sample_data(): 
        optimizer.apply_gradients(loss)

print(p_s)
```

However the above obviously does not run because the placeholder `data` inside the loss function does not exist anymore - however I am not sure how to replace it. :S

Anyone? *Note that I don't have a* `def forward(x)` *because my input* `datum` *isn't transformed - it is used directly to calculate the loss.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the conversion tool (that exists, but I don't like it since it just prefixes (more or less) the API calls with `tf.compat.v1` and uses the old Tensoflow 1.x API) I help you convert your code to the new version.

Sessions are disappeared, and so are the placeholders. The reason? The code is executed line by line - that is the Tensorflow eager mode.

To train a model you correctly have to use an optimizer. If you want to use the `minimize` method, in Tensorflowe 2.0 you have to define the function to minimize (the loss) as a Python callable.

```py
# This is your "model"
theta = tf.Variable(np.zeros(100))
p_s = tf.nn.softmax(theta)

# Define the optimizer
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()

# Define the training loop with the loss inside (because we use the
# .minimnize method that requires a callable with no arguments)

trainable_variables = [theta]

for epoch in range(10):
    for datum in sample_data():
        # The loss must be callable and return the value to minimize
        def loss_fn():
            loss = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.math.log(tf.gather(p_s, datum)))
            return loss
        optimizer.minimize(loss_fn, var_list=trainable_variables)
    tf.print("epoch ", epoch, " finished. ps: ", p_s)
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tested the code - but it should work (or at least give you an idea on how to implement what you're trying to achieve in TF 2)

Comment: Wow. Thanks. I'm away from my computer until later today when I'll execute the code and report back on whether it works. Thanks again +1

Comment: I'm curious to know whether (1) the @tf.function decorator is needed on the loss function (2) whether tf.gradienttape is needed?

Comment: tf.function is never needed - converting a function to its graph representation is not mandatory, is just recommended when eager is slow. If you want to add it somewhere in this train, just decorate the whole training script (hence, put it in a function and decorate it) and execute the whole training using a graph.

(2): gradient tape is needed when you dont' want to use the `minimize` method, hence when you have a complex loss function, when you want more flexibility, and when you want to process the gradients before applying the update rule of the chosen optimizer.

Comment: Hi @nessuno, I get an error when I run the code: `ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['Variable:0'].` For some reason I guess it's not understanding that theta is a trainable variable

Comment: Try replacing in the loss function `p_s` with `tf.nn.softmax(theta)` and see if it works.

Comment: Yes. Replacing p_s with tf.nn.softmax(theta) fixed the problem. But why? This kind of problem wouldn't occur in tensorflow1.13 - i.e. there was no issue doing a `sess.run` on intermediate variables. Is there a way around it so that I can call intermediate variables like p_s directly? (Also do you want to update the answer so I can tick it as correct)

Comment: Note that I had to also change `print(p_s)` at the end to `print(tf.nn.softmax(theta))` as `print(p_s)` was producing the incorrect result. More specifically it would print out the result of `tf.nn.softmax(tf.constant(np.zeros(100)))` at every epoch. I.e. it would just print out the softmax of a zero vector at every epoch

Comment: It's perhaps better to open a new question about this; in the meantime since my answer solved your initial problem please mark it as accepted!